# Design patterns advice - separating ViewModels from domain models

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection

I need to separate ViewModels in my MVC project from my business models (Data access layer) which lives in a separate library.

Assume that I have Database Access Layer classes in a separate library. Our primary project (MVC) does know nothing about those classes and they talk to each other through an Interface. It’s easy enough to use IOC and resolve dependency injection using Ninject or something, right?

Now DataAccessLayer contains class named Car with properties Engine and Wheel. In my MVC project (which doesn’t know nothing about DataAccessLayer and its classes) I need to use some Car objects. So I have another Car class (it’s just a pure ViewModel) and it has the same properties – Engine and Wheel (of course in real app there will be some differences between model and viewmodel, for the sake of simplicity let’s ignore that)

IDataAccessLayer Interface has a method called IEnumerable GetAllCars() that returns list of DataAccessLayer.Car objects.
[image]
Now I need to create MVCProject.Car collection,  iterate through IEnumerable which was returned by GetAllCars(),  on every iteration I need to create a new  MVCProject.Car object, populate Engine and Wheel properties, and finally add that object to the Collection.

So: everytime I have to create almost the same structures and somehow manage them in different places.

Here is the problem, see? Or it isn’t? I feel like it will end up into big mess if I don’t change that. Don’t repeat yourself principle violation as it is. Tell me please how to make it right. Using I don’t know proxies or prototypes or maybe some other design pattern which I suck anyway. Or some sort of a tool like Ninject (which I only know how to use as IOC container) or Automapper or whatever, which I probably will suck even more than I suck in design patterns.

Comment: you don't suck... at least you're thinking about design patterns :-)

Comment: Please change the title to indicate what you are asking about.

Comment: @David: Amen to that brother!

Comment: David Archer or "you don't suck... you're thinking *in* design patterns" :-/

Comment: @marcind.. Should I put a question mark at the end? :)

Comment: Well the biggest problem is - mapping properties from Model to ViewModel. I'm thinking of using Automapper for that. I guess the problem would be then - how to separate Model, ViewModel and Mapping logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also don't see much of a reason to keep the DAL separate from the MVC layer. In case you're interested, here is the layout that I've used for multiple project and I find it is very usable and flexible.

**DataObjects**
Basic objects with only properties. Also includes enumerations which the DataObjects use.

**DataAccess**
Inherit from DataObjects and add GetByPrimaryKey, GetByForeignKey, GetByUniqueIndex, GetAll, etc., etc. Also contains the Caching layer where you would find StateCache, CountryCache, etc. for quick access to frequently used things. The "GetBy" methods will utilize the caching layer whenever possible.

**Logic**
Static classes, one for each DataObject\Access type. Includes logical work other than simple fetches as detailed in the DataAccess layer.

**Web\Front-end**
UI works with DataAccess and Logic layers to get and update objects as well as call other defined logical APIs.

I use my own custom-made code generator to generate 98% of this code (except the UI layer).

Comment: Well that's certainly a fair archtecture, but out of curiosity, since you're generating your own DAL, how do you handle complex queries like all customers who's birthday is before 3/22/1982 that have at least one order of amount > $100, ordered by last name?

Comment: The DAL in this case is using LINQ-to-SQL and since this layer is accessible from the UI layer, it's as simple as writing a LINQ query. Of course if it is something that is reusable then it goes in the Logic layer.

Comment: Ahh - that's really neat then - especially since 98% of that is generated.  Cool.  +1

Comment: Thanks. Eventually it will be available for general use. If I get time!

Comment: Have you blogged about it at all?  You might want to adapt it to EF4 - linq-to-sql is about dead...

Comment: Wow..wow..wow... that's very sweet. I need to learn how to do that.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sure to let you two know when/if the generator is available.

Comment: RE: EF4 - the CodeGenerator will do whatever you tell it to do. I happen to be using LINQ still but EF4 or any other framework can be implemented.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your MVC library *should* know about your data-access library, shouldn't it?

Or, if you really want to keep your MVC and DAL libraries separate, you could always add a third library with references to both MVC and DAL.  Then it could handle retrieving cars from the one library, and converting them to the other.

But again, I don't see why your controllers (or ViewModel, from what you've described) shouldn't have access to the DAL.  Your car ViewModel would retrieve instances of Cars from the DAL, and go from there.  So long as the **way in which** it receives the cars is coded through an interface, you should be able to stub that out later for your unit tests.

**EDIT**

So it looks like you think you'll be changing the entire DAL around later, and you want to minimize the difficulty of that?  If that's the case, you might look at the [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).  You would pass all your DAL objects to adapters, which would return to you objects in your business layer.  Then, if your DAL changes, you just update your adapters.

Comment: still struggling. I need to Change GetCars methods into probably generic that will take Type of ViewModel.Car and return collection of IEnumerable<ViewModel.Car>. But the data should be mapped from AccessDataLayer.Car type

Comment: +1: the ability to change your data access layer is fool's gold that gives you no real benefits. To see why, read [Abstracting the persistence medium isn't going to let you switch](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/08/02/abstracting-the-persistence-medium-isnrsquot-going-to-let-you-switch.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it really ugly :)

The Goal: Caller doesn't know nothing about Model Entities at DataAccessLayer, and gets all the data through the interface. 
How to get the data without manual mapping between Model and Viewmodel? 
Through reflection.

```
 public IEnumerable<T> GetCars<T>()
    {
        var lst = new List<T>();

        _data.GetTable<Cars>().ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            var newCar = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            typeof(T).GetProperty("Engine").SetValue(newCar, x.Engine, null);
            typeof(T).GetProperty("Wheel").SetValue(newCar, x.Wheel, null);
            lst.Add(newCar);
        });

        return lst;
    }
```

It Works. But the biggest question here is it fair and considerable architectural decision? How the performance will be affected in a real life app?

Comment: You should *not* be using reflection for something like this.  If you need to map one type to another, use an adapter.  This is an extremely fragile solution.

Comment: @Adam: second that. Any time you see a property name in quotes, you're doing something "wrong." Or at least it's probably not the best way. Also using reflection in code that is the heart of your application will result in performance issues. See my answer for more regarding my suggestions.

Comment: @Adam of course that's heretical and never should be used :) Just as an example of finding non-traditional and ugly solutions. Gee I really suck in software architecture design :)

Comment: No, you don't suck - you're just trying too hard.  Just throttle back a little, allow slightly more dependencies (like MVC depending on DAL) and a very clear solution will emerge.  You're doing fine.

Comment: I'm rooting for automapper.codeplex.com. Guys what do you think?